# How to convert an mp3 to mp4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I just got ffmpeg installed on my linux server.  I am attempting to convert an mp3 file to an mp4 file.

I have this jpg image: `/public_html/wp-content/channels/image.jpg`
I have this mp3 file: `/public_html/wp-content/channels/file.mp3`

```
$mp3 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/channels/file.mp3";
$image = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/wp-content/channels/image.jpg"; 

    $commands = array(
        '-i $mp3',
        '-vn test.mp4'
    );

    shell_exec("ffmpeg".implode(' ',$commands));
```

This is my first time using ffmpeg.  Have i done this correctly?  How do i add an image to the video file?

Comment: This might help you: https://superuser.com/a/99071